# creating child windows in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am creating a program using wxpython which entails the need to create many sub-windows for each of menubar items. I am currently creating those sub-windows by writing different class definition for each and instantiating those classes for each event. Is this better than to have wx.window? How does two compare and what are the situations where they should be used?

Comment: It is difficult to answer you with no example code and without information on the functionality you try to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each toolbar item is to open a new "window", then I would recommend a wx.Frame or wx.Dialog. You almost never need to use wx.Window directly. wx.Window is the parent of wx.Frame and wx.Dialog. As such, wx.Frame and wx.Dialog potentially add additional functionality.

Dialogs are modal and should be used when you want program execution to stop while the dialog is dealt with (like when you need to get special information to complete some task). Frames are used when you don't need to stop program execution.

Comment: thanks Mike! I was looking for the answer like you provided rather than coming back and saying I did not provide sufficient information.